# launch nm-openvpn via cli

Tags: command-line, cron, vpn, gui

I am using MX linux and i need next thing. I have a config for openvpn, it works perfectly both from manual launch via cli and from nm-openvpn application in my XFCE.

I want to launch my openvpn every morning at 9 am via cron, but with visual displaying in my XFCE like i launched it from GUI.

Which command does networkmanager launch when i click "connect to vpn"? I was trying to analyze ps -aux | grep openvpn output and syslog, but without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no non-networkmanager command that is being launched when you activate the openvpn connection through NM. This is an internal procedure within NM that sets up the connection. To manipulate it through the command line you can use the `nmcli` command. Some kind of command like this should work:

```
nmcli connect up "name of the openvpn connection"
```

Instead of the name of the VPN connection you can use the ID, UUID or PATH of the connection.